# Print a Connect 4 board

Tags: python, homework, connect-four

I am required to code (as part of a 3-question assignment) a variable-size connect 4 board with a standard size of 6x7, with a minimum size of 2x2 and a maximum of 20x20. The professor said that he could do it in 20 lines, and the maximum one can write is 3 times that. My code sits uncomfortably close to it at 58 lines. What can I do to cut it down without using user-defined functions?

```py
r, c, p, a, std, b = 0, 0, 0, '', input('Standard game? (y/n): '), ' '
if std == 'y':
    r, c = 6, 7
else: 
    r, c = int(input('r? (2 - 20): ')), int(input('c? (2 - 20): '))
if r < 11 and c < 11:
    for i in range (r-1, -1, -1): 
        a = str(i)
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + str(' ·') #repeats the dot for j times
        print(a + ' ')
    for j in range (c):
        b = b + ' ' + str(j) #adds successive nos. to the bottom row, ie the index
    print(b + ' ')
elif r < 11 and c >= 11:
    a, b = ' ', '  '
    for i in range (r-1, -1, -1):
        a = ' ' + str(i) + ' '
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + ' ' + str('· ')
        print(a)
    for j in range (10):
        b = b + '  ' + str(j)
    for j in range (10, c):
        b = b + ' ' + str(j)
    print(b + ' ')
elif r >= 11 and c < 11:
    b = '  '
    for i in range (r-1, 9, -1): 
        a = str(i) + ' '
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + str(' · ')
        print(a) #repeats the dot for j times for j >= 10 (i.e. no space)
    for i in range (9, -1, -1): 
        a = ' ' + str(i) + ' '
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + str(' · ')
        print(a) #repeats the dot for j times for j < 10 (space)    
    for j in range (c):
        b = b + '  ' + str(j)
    print(b + ' ')
else:
    a, b = ' ', '  '
    for i in range (r-1, 9, -1): 
        a = str(i) + ' '
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + str(' · ')
        print(a) #repeats the dot for j times for j >= 10 (i.e. no space)
    for i in range (9, -1, -1): 
        a = ' ' + str(i) + ' '
        for j in range (c):
            a = a + str(' · ')
        print(a)
    for j in range (10):
        b = b + '  ' + str(j)
    for j in range (10, c):
        b = b + ' ' + str(j)
    print(b + ' ')
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use user-defined functions? What kind of class is this?

Answer (score 2):

I will focus on creating a readable, maintainable and scalable implementation. Even without sacrificing readbaility (by avoiding things like multiple variable assignments per line), this implementation comes in at only 15 lines. This number could be reduced further by inlining some variables, etc. but I don't think that's worth doing here.

Please note that this does not include proper validation of user input, which is generally a good idea.

---

**Complete code**

I added some blank lines for the sake of readability:

```
standard_game = input('Standard game? (y/n): ').lower() == "y"

if standard_game:
    ROWS = 6
    COLUMNS = 7
else:
    ROWS = int(input('ROWS? (2 - 20): '))
    COLUMNS = int(input('COLUMNS? (2 - 20): '))
    
width_y_axis_elements = len(str(ROWS - 1))
width_x_axis_elements = len(str(COLUMNS - 1)) + 1

dots = '·'.rjust(width_x_axis_elements) * COLUMNS

for i in range(ROWS - 1, -1, -1):
    label = str(i).rjust(width_y_axis_elements)
    print(f"{label}{dots}")
    
x_axis = ''.join(map(lambda s: s.rjust(width_x_axis_elements), map(str, range(COLUMNS))))
print(f"{' ' * width_y_axis_elements}{x_axis}")
```

The key to simplifying this implementation is realizing that `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` being below or above 10 aren't actually special cases. You only need to consider the length of the highest number on each axis and then pad everything accordingly. For this we use [`str.rjust`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rjust.asp). Once you understand this conceptually, the implementation is rather straightforward. Don't hesitate to ask for clarifiction if necessary!

Comment: Thanks for your input! My class hasn't introduced str.rjust or f threads yet, so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use this, but I'll take that idea in mind.

Comment: You can easily replace f-strings with string concatenation, so `f"{label}{dots}"` becomes `label + dots`. You could also implement `str.rjust` on your own by checking the length of your input string, comparing it to the desired length and adding spaces to the front of the string until the desired length is reached.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it in just *3 lines*!

Here is the code:

```
if input('Standard game? (y/n): ') == 'y': r, c = 6, 7
else: r, c = int(input('r? (2 - 20): ')), int(input('c? (2 - 20): '))
print('\n'.join([*[str(i).ljust(2) + ' .' + '  .' * (c - 1) for i in range(r)], *[' '+''.join([str(i).rjust(3) for i in range(c)])]]))
```

I will explain it step by step

- `if input('Standard game? (y/n): ') == 'y': r, c = 6, 7`
  This line is rather simple, it takes input and checks if it is equal to `'y'`, if so then `r, c = 6, 7`.
- `else: r, c = int(input('r? (2 - 20): ')), int(input('c? (2 - 20): '))`
  Else we take input for `r, c`.
- Now the main line, I will split it in multiple lines to explain.

You can refer about [`.join()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join), [`.ljust()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/ljust) and [`.rjust()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/rjust).

`*[str(i).ljust(2) + ' .' + '  .' * (c - 1) for i in range(r)]`

This will just get the string representation of the row indexes and the rows and unpack it.

`*[' '+''.join([str(i).rjust(3) for i in range(c)])`

This will get the string representation for the column indexes and unpack it.

Finally, we join them with a `'\n'` and print it.

Thats it!

Happy Coding!

### Edit

I was able to do it in *2 lines* using a tenary operator.

```
r, c = (6, 7) if input('Standard game? (y/n): ') == 'y' else (int(input('r? (2 - 20): ')), int(input('c? (2 - 20): ')))
print('\n'.join([*[str(i).ljust(2) + ' .' + '  .' * (c - 1) for i in range(r - 1, -1, -1)], *[' '+''.join([str(i).rjust(3) for i in range(c)])]]))
```

Comment: Your 2-line solution numbers the y-axis the wrong way round, you'll need to change `range(r)` to `range(r - 1, -1, -1)`.

Comment: You are correct. Updated my answer accordingly.